# UPDATE with RETURNING values of UPDATE in CTE, 0 rows affected

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

UPD: thanks to @S-Man for simpler example

I updated a table (just one row) within a CTE. I give out the updated values with the `RETURNING` clause. Now I am trying to update the same row again using the values from the `RETURNING` clause. As result I am getting "0 rows affected".

(The problem here is a much simplified version of a more complex code with more sense)

**I cannot explain this behaviour.**

```
CREATE TABLE items (
    id int
);

INSERT INTO items VALUES (1);


WITH abc AS (
    UPDATE items
    SET id = id + 1
    RETURNING 42
)
UPDATE items
SET id = (SELECT id FROM abc LIMIT 1)
RETURNING *
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=fd18b64b8c61905b6ad1aed229efbb7b)

I noticed, when i put more rows into `items`, it returns n - 1 rows.
[4 rows](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=9acd87523aceb4803c58cc2bf24af6d9)

Comment: I don't know the reason for that behaviour but you should simply your query as much as possible. This fiddle has the same behaviour: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=9a7a37ae77a021814f09c32c0fe0074a It seems like you can't do two updates in one query to one table. Maybe the first UPDATE is not persisted yet so that the table cannot be updated a second time... or something like that. Nevertheless for readability and debugging purposes I would recommend to do this in two separate query.

Comment: @S-Man Thanks! Updated.

Comment: Edited your text to make the problem more clearer. I am also interested in solving the phenomenon. I really cannot explain it as well.